# Replace the launch icon from the command-line (Android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, command-line

I have an app in android studio. I created a launcher icon with a foreground and background PNGs. This works fine.

Now I want to clone this app to make a white-label version for a customer. Change name, some behavior, colors, etc. I have a bash script that does that nicely for me. I can even inject a Java class to modify behavior. Then I build and ship.

The problem I am having is with the launcher icon. When I first created it in Asset Studio, I just selected the background image, the foreground image. It then generated those images in multiple formats. For example, with xxhdpi:

```
$ ls ./app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/
ic_launcher_background.png  ic_launcher_foreground.png  ic_launcher.png  ic_launcher_round.png
```

The background and foreground images are just resized versions of my resources, but the two other files are "rendered" versions of my icon, one square and one rounded. I am for now overriding them with ImageMagick, but I feel that's not the way to do it.

My question is: Is it possible to replace the background and foreground and have Android Studio regenerate the "rendered" versions of the icons from the command-line ?

Comment: The SDK is not generating those icons. Android Studio is. There are plenty of command-line tools for image manipulation (e.g., ImageMagick).

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks, that's exactly what I'm doing right now. It still feels silly to redo manually what Android Studio can do for me. I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Android Studio does not do anything from the command line, other than launch its UI

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. I guess I'm out of luck then.